# C++ - Vector iterator not incrementable error

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have myVector with some values of the type *Texture_Map* which is just an `int`.

I'm not erasing anything... I just want to insert a value in each even iteration.

Something like:
If I have this vector `[1,2,3,4,5]`

And my `Texture_Map::TEXTURE_FLIP` is `99`, then my final vector should be:

```
[99,1,99,2,99,3,99,4,99,5]
```

After the first `insert()` I get the "**Vector iterator not incrementable problem**" error.

The code:

```
myVector.push_back(Texture_Map::TEXTURE_INIT);

for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < m_max_pieces-2; i++)
    myVector.push_back((Texture_Map::TextureID)i);

std::random_shuffle(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());

std::vector<Texture_Map::TextureID>::iterator it = myVector.begin();

for (it=myVector.begin(); it<myVector.end(); it++)
{
    myVector.insert(it,Texture_Map::TEXTURE_FLIP);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of the consequence of using [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) on a vector is that it:

> Causes reallocation if the new size() is greater than the old capacity(). If the new size() is greater than capacity(), all iterators and references are invalidated. Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated.

The issue you're seeing is that you're attempting to increment an iterator which is no longer valid - it's past the insertion point, so it's invalidated. The solution here is to take advantage of that fact that `insert` returns an `iterator`:

```
iterator insert( iterator pos, const T& value );
```

Specifically:

> Return value
>   1-2) Iterator pointing to the inserted value

So you want:

```
for (it=myVector.begin(); it<myVector.end(); it++) {
    // now it will point to TEXTURE_FLIP
    it = myVector.insert(it,Texture_Map::TEXTURE_FLIP);

    // now it will point back to the original element
    ++it;
}
```

Comment: Could you point where the standard explicitly states that iterators at and after the insertion point become invalid?

Comment: @AlexD It only requires that those before the insertion point remain valid, it doesn't state that they become invalid. However, it doesn't require that they remain valid either - so better to assume they're not.

Comment: No doubt that it is safer to assume that all iterators are invalidated. My point was rather that the quote from cppreference is not 100% accurate saying _"Otherwise, only the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid. The past-the-end iterator is also invalidated."_.